# how to read incoming data from socket in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I create a socket in my android app, when I connect to server I create an `InputStream` for this socket to read incoming data from server:

```
socket = new Socket(address, port);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int bytesRead;
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
         while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
             byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
             // the execution is blocked at this line and does not get out  
             //from the while
         }
  }
```

After getting the input stream I try to read bytes and fill a String(response) but it blocks within the `while`-loop when reading all the data from server. This means that the condition in while is not satisfied. I'm sending phrases like this: "hello how are you"

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Sockets

Comment: im sending messages from c# code (console application in server side)

Comment: `I'm sending phrases like this: "hello how are you"`. You could better let the server send phrases or lines like "hello how are you?\n". And in your client use a BufferedInputStreamReader or so to be able to use .readLine(). If you only send texts you will be fine.

Comment: i try .readLine() like this  `BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
          response+=line;
      }` but when i read the first line its block until i send another line, so same result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should break while loop when \n arrive or something like that from server. Loop is still waiting for new data to read.